# What's a natural way to say that someone works somewhere (for a job)?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Normally I would use  일 하다 to express that I (or someone else) works somewhere - e.g. 나는 출판사에서 일한다. But I wonder if this is a bit 'childish', or if it focuses on the action of working rather than the state/status of having a particular job.

What are natural ways to make statements like "I work in a publishing company", "I work from home", "I work for Samsung" ?

Comment: The present tense and present progressive tense are good to express “states.” Just like English.

Comment: I think 근무하다, 직업하다 can be used

Answer (score 6):

To me, at talking a job, childish is natural.

I work in a publishing company

출판사에서 일합니다.

I am in a publishing company 출판사에 있어요

I go to a publishing company 출판사 다녀요

If we have a particular job, for instance lawyer. It has a character as like a free
  lancer, then we can express the state easily. But, as like office man, if he is in an organization,
  then we do not know well about a ranking or a position. Hence usually, we say one in the above three
and give a business card.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the use of "다니다"

Answer (score 4):

You already know the most natural way to say that.

"나는 출판사에서 일한다" sounds perfectly normal in a neutral context. "일하다" conveys both meanings of (1) the action of working ("오늘은 대충 일했다." I didn't work hard today.) and (2) having the status of a particular job.

"I work from home" would be "나는 집에서 일한다" and "I work for Samsung" "나는 삼성에서 일한다."

Some more examples from the Korea University Korean Language Dictionary:

(1) To mean *the action of working*,

그는 아내를 잃고 나서 두 아들을 잘 키워 내기 위해 부지런히 일했다.

He worked hard to raise his two sons after losing his wife.

(2) To mean *the status of having a particular job position*,

나는 중년이 되면 사회봉사 기관에서 일할 생각이다.

I'm thinking of working for a social service organization in my middle years.

Answer (score 3):

For that, you can also use `근무하다` instead of `일하다`. Although it may not be as natural as `일하다` would sound, it's always a good way to go for formal statements.

---

> 출판사에서 근무하였다. 근무하고 있다.

---

> 출판사에서 근무한 경력이 있다.

---

> 재택근무하다.

---

> ㅇㅇ(회사)에서 ㅇㅇ(직책/직무)(으)로 근무하였다.